# Horizontal spacing in subplot matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a subplot with the grid (1X7). I am trying to adjust the spacing between the two subplots.

I used the subplots_adjust option with the left and right spacing specified. But it does not seem to work. Below is the main code for subplots

````
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,7,sharey=True,figsize=(12,10))
fig.subplots_adjust(left= 0.1, right=0.9, bottom = 0.1, top = 0.9, wspace=0.2) 
cs = axs[0].contour(xx,yy,tm_true.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[0].text(0.4, -0.04, '(a)', transform=axs[0].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

cs = axs[1].contour(xx,yy,tm_romgp.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[1].text(0.4, -0.04, '(b)', transform=axs[1].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

cs = axs[2].contour(xx,yy,tm_s1.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[2].text(0.4, -0.04, '(c)', transform=axs[2].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

cs = axs[3].contour(xx,yy,tm_e1.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[3].text(0.4, -0.04, '(d)', transform=axs[3].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

cs = axs[4].contour(xx,yy,tm_l1.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[4].text(0.4, -0.04, '(e)', transform=axs[4].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

cs = axs[5].contour(xx,yy,tm_b21.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[5].text(0.4, -0.04, '(f)', transform=axs[5].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

cs = axs[6].contour(xx,yy,tm_b31.T, 40, cmap='inferno', interpolation='bilinear')
axs[0].text(0.4, -0.04, '(g)', transform=axs[6].transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

fig.tight_layout() 

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.08)

cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.22, -0.05, 0.6, 0.04])
fig.colorbar(cs, cax=cbar_ax, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()

fig.savefig("temp_twoleg.png", bbox_inches = 'tight')
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFRkt.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Because `tight_layout` will overwrite any settings to the subplot parameters, it does not make sense to call `tight_layout` after `subplots_adjust`. Easiest is to just remove the `tight_layout` line from your script.